# Set Localization in OpenSocial gadgets

Tags: opensocial, google-gadget

I want to use the localization feature of OpenSocial. But I want to set the used language manually. I only found prefs.getLang() to read the current language. Is there a possibility to set it also?

```
<Module>
<ModulePrefs>
    <Require feature="opensocial-0.9"/>
    <Require feature="embedded-experiences"/>
    <Require feature="dynamic-height"/>
    <Require feature="setprefs"/>
    <Locale lang="de" messages=".../locale/de_ALL.xml"/>
    <Locale lang="en" messages=".../locale/en_ALL.xml"/>
</ModulePrefs>
<UserPref ...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the opensocial-container should choose the right locale by itself. Found no possibility to do it manually.